# How are order discounts transfered to invoice and creditmemo?

Tags: event-observer, invoice, creditmemo, fieldsets

I want to copy some attributes from order to invoice and creditmemo, but adjust them dependent on the `discount_amount` attribute of the target.

I wrote an observer for `core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_order_to_invoice` and `core_copy_fieldset_sales_convert_order_to_cm` but at this point, the value is not set yet. I also could not find any corresponding fieldset configuration in `Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`.

So my question is: Where does Magento set these values when it converts orders? And do I need to fall back to `sales_invoice_save_before` and `sales_creditmemo_save_before` events or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discount Amount would come from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice_Total_Discount`but there are not many events around so the ones you mentioned might be the best avenue.